# how to use "sinatra/reloader"?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I have my `web.rb` where I have

```
require 'rubygems' 
require 'sinatra'  
require "sinatra/reloader"
```

Then I start my web application by double click on the web.rb short cut. After any change in web.rb I have to exit the sinatra and run it again.

I thought that "sinatra/reloader" would help me not to manual reaload.

**configuration (MS Windows)**

- ruby 1.8.7 (2010-08-16 patchlevel 302) [i386-mingw32]
- sinatra (1.2.6, 1.0)
- sinatra-advanced-routes (0.5.1)
- sinatra-reloader (0.5.0)
- sinatra-sugar (0.5.1, 0.5.0)
- thin (1.2.7 x86-mswin32)

Comment: it works for me. what version of sinatra and ruby are you using?

Comment: It's pretty strange. It works for me on this configuration. anyway, you can try to use http://www.sinatrarb.com/faq.html#reloading this method. BTW, have you tried all these methods? https://github.com/rkh/sinatra-reloader/blob/master/README.md

Comment: I tried only the first method = `require "sinatra/reloader"`. Shotgun doesn't work on windows

Comment: what kind of changes in web.rb do you make?

Comment: like adding new view (get '/tt' do  
  haml :tt
end ) or changing ruby code. I have some functions there...

Comment: is it work for you with one file? just `get "/" do "Hello" end` and then add another route, without view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I start my web application from **dos prompt** via "**ruby web.rb**" everything works fine

if I start my web application

- via double click web.rb or
- from batch file

the application starts but sinatra-reload doesn't work

@nash thank you for your help

Answer (score 5):

```
register Sinatra::Reloader
```

I changed to rack-reloader months back, realized it didn't work well even with hacks
switched back and forgot to use `register`

the drawback of sinatra sometimes is the slightly more wisdom-of-crowds documentation

Comment: At the top of the Sinatra subclass.